Where should non-root-user programs write the data which system-level programs write to (subdirectories of) /var?
Background
Unix convention and the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy standard define several paths under which processes look for certain information, or use to write certain information. When one needs to setup a user-specific environment, as a non-root user - most of those locations are either inaccessible, or readable but without the ability to write to files or create new ones. So, one must use alternatives.
In principle, we could just treat a user's home directory like another /; however, that's not common practice.
There is also the custom of creating a $HOME/.my_app directory. Most apps which create those use those for configuration, but some also for other kinds of data (Eclipse, Firefox, Thunderbird come to mind as hiding gobs of data in there). But that means we may have dozens if not hundreds of .something in the home directory, which is quite unseemly.
Finally, it has also become common for some apps to write into $HOME/.local and $HOME/.config, which does not "litter" the home directory itself: $HOME/.config can be seen as an equivalent of /etc and $HOME.local of /usr; so, quite useful, but - it doesn't cover /var and its subdirectories.
Actual question
Where, under a user's home directory, should we, or should a program we write, store the data which a system-level program would store in /var, or subdirectories of /var? That is to say: "files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system, such as logs [and] spool... files" (to quote the FHS), as well as cache, non-static databases, lock files, run files and log files?

/var is a bit generic; it's used for very different things (/var/tmp, /var/cache, /var/lib/… are very different), and they map to different user-specific directories. Maybe you have a concrete example to clarify?

@MarcusMüller: Rephrased to (hopefully) clarify. I'm asking about all sorts of /var'ish things.

please don't ask about "all sorts" of things. that is obviously like asking for us to copy out a full guideline where to put files. Be specific. We can start with one, and maybe the documentation we can refer you to for that answers the other questions, but when we start with all things that might be under /var, we'll never get anywhere.

I think the closest equivalent is $XDG_STATE_HOME:

$XDG_STATE_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user-specific state files should be stored. If $XDG_STATE_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/state should be used.
The $XDG_STATE_HOME contains state data that should persist between (application) restarts, but that is not important or portable enough to the user that it should be stored in $XDG_DATA_HOME. It may contain:

actions history (logs, history, recently used files, …)
current state of the application that can be reused on a restart (view, layout, open files, undo history, …)


Some data you’d find in /var doesn’t fit in the above however, or not comfortably. For example, there’s no real $HOME equivalent for /var/tmp, but all users are supposed to be allowed to write in /var/tmp anyway. As another example, data that would go in /var/cache when written by “system” applications should really go in $XDG_CACHE_HOME ($HOME/.cache) when written by user applications.
